# C# Error: Unknown column 'group' in 'field list' - while running MySql procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I got the error `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'group' in 'field list'` only if the procedure is run from my C# application. To be more confused for me this error is not happening for every execution of the procedure from my application, but sometimes. For the same data in the table sometimes I got the error, sometimes not. When the procedure is run from some MySql Management Studio I never got this kind of error.

This is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE TestProcedure()
BEGIN

-- creating temporary table
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Duplicates_tmp (
    field1 TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    field2 TEXT DEFAULT NULL
  );

-- insert duplicates from keys in temp table (one row of every duplicates)
INSERT INTO Duplicates_tmp (field1, field2)
SELECT Field1, Field2
  FROM keys
GROUP BY Field2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

-- delete all duplicates from table Key
DELETE from keys where Field2 IN (SELECT field2 from Duplicates_tmp);

-- insert one row of every duplicates found
  INSERT INTO keys (Field1, Field2)
    SELECT field1, field2
  FROM Duplicates_tmp;

END
```

The procedure is called with this C# code:

```
MySqlConnection mysql_con = new MySqlConnection();
mysql_con = new MySqlConnection(connection_string);

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = mysql_con;
cmd.CommandText = "CALL TestProcedure";

mysql_con.Open();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120000;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
mysql_con.Close();
```

Comment: Very bad idea to use reserved keywords as field names.

Comment: I set the field names to be on English just to show you the example.. in the real case they are in other language (grupa, kluc) instead of (group, key).

Comment: `group` is a reserved keyword and there are many more  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html , you should avoid them using in table name or field name and incase you really need to use backtick them.

Comment: I have changed the fields to: field1, field2 instead of group, key.